# MockMvc and Mockito - java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$" Expected: a collection with size <2> but: collection size was <0>

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I have no idea why I am getting this error here. Any thoughts?

Here is my repository code

```
package movieweb.movies.repository;

import movieweb.movies.models.Movies;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MoviesRepository extends CrudRepository<Movies, Integer> {
}
```

Here is my Controller code.

```
package movieweb.movies.controllers;
import movieweb.movies.models.Movies;
import movieweb.movies.models.UserMovies;
import movieweb.movies.repository.MoviesRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

@RestController
public class MoviesController {

    @Autowired
    private MoviesRepository moviesRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(path = "/movies")
    public  List<Movies> movies(){
        List<Movies> allMovies = (List<Movies>) moviesRepository.findAll();
        if (!allMovies.isEmpty()){
            return allMovies;
        } else {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Movies not found"
            );
        }


    }

//    @CrossOrigin
//    @RequestMapping(path = "movies/user/{id}")
//    public List<Movies> movie(@PathVariable("id") int id){
//        return this.movies().stream().map(movie -> {
//            Users[] user = restTemplate.getForObject("http://127.0.0.1:8082/users/" + id, Users[].class);
//            return new Movies(movie.getMovieId(), movie.getMovieName(), "Description");
//        })
//                .collect(Collectors.toList());
//    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(path="/movie/{id}")
    public  Movies getMovie(@PathVariable Integer id){
        return moviesRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(
                HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Movie not found"
        ) );
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @DeleteMapping("/movie/delete/{id}")
    void deleteMovie(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        moviesRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @PutMapping("/movie/update/{id}")
    Movies updateMovie(@RequestBody Movies updateMovie, @PathVariable Integer id) {

        return moviesRepository.findById(id)
                .map(Movies -> {
                    Movies.setMovieName(updateMovie.getMovieName());
                    Movies.setMovieDescription(updateMovie.getMovieDescription());
                    return moviesRepository.save(Movies);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    updateMovie.setMovieId(id);
                    return moviesRepository.save(updateMovie);
                });
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(path="/newMovie")
    public Movies addNewMovie (@RequestBody Movies data) {
       return moviesRepository.save(data);
    }


}
```

and here is my test (**updated**)

```
package movieweb.movies;
import movieweb.movies.controllers.MoviesController;
import movieweb.movies.models.Movies;
import movieweb.movies.repository.MoviesRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc

class MovieApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    MoviesRepository moviesRepository;

    @MockBean
    MoviesController moviesController;


    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

    }

    @Test
    void getAllMovies() throws Exception{

        ArrayList<Movies> moviesList = new ArrayList<Movies>();
        moviesList.add(new Movies(1, "Star Wars", "A New Hope"));
        moviesList.add(new Movies(2, "Star Wars", "Empire Strikes Back"));

            when(moviesRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(moviesList);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/movies"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].movieName", is("Star Wars")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].movieDescription", is("A New Hope")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].movieName", is("Star Wars")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].movieDescription", is("Empire Strikes Back")));


        Mockito.verify(moviesRepository, times(1)).findAll();
    }
}
```

The error I am getting in my stacktrace is the following....

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$"
Expected: a collection with size <2>
     but: collection size was <0>
```

Why is it zero and not the 2 items I created in my movieList ArrayList?

I'm guessing its something to do with my configuration?

Comment: `moviesRepository` is mocked ? can you show the complete test class code ?

Comment: @Deadpool see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mocking your controller:

```
@MockBean
MoviesController moviesController;
```

Thus, you replaced the real controller under test with this mock.
To have real controller you need to get rid of these lines.

To further improve, learn about @WebMvcTest to test only the web slice of your app.

Comment: Yep that was the problem thanks. I'm learning about all this stuff now Ill look into the @WebMvcTest too thanks again.